# stretch propto for long stackrel

Tags: amsmath

I want to be able to do
`\stackrel{\xi,\eta}{\propto}`

but the resulting formula looks ugly in the `\propto` part:[image]

Help to stretch the “propto” sign horizontally?

Comment: By "stretch", are you asking for a larger vertical gap?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I editted the post.

Answer (score 1):

The top line tries to recreate the OP's situation.  In the second line, I replace the `\stackrel` with a math-mode `\stackon`, specifying a 3pt stacking gap.  In the last line, I redo the second line, except I ignore the width of the stacked material when computing the horizontal spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$p(\xi,\eta\mid x) \stackrel{\xi,\eta}{\propto}
 p(x\mid\xi,\eta)\cdot p(\xi,\eta)$

\medskip
$p(\xi,\eta\mid x) \mathrel{\stackon[3pt]{\propto}{\scriptstyle\xi,\eta}}
 p(x\mid\xi,\eta)\cdot p(\xi,\eta)$

\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\medskip
$p(\xi,\eta\mid x) \mathrel{\stackon[3pt]{\propto}{\scriptstyle\xi,\eta}}
 p(x\mid\xi,\eta)\cdot p(\xi,\eta)$
\end{document}
```

[image]